# What is this proprety of the select tag?

Tags: html, css

[image: An image]

There is this strange white border around the options of this select tag, I don't know what causes it and I would like to get rid of it.

I tried setting `"ouline:0;"` but it didn't work. I was hoping this white border would go away.

Html:

```
<select name="filtro" id="status">
   <option value="encerrado">Encerrado</option>
   <option value="pendente">Pendente</option>
</select>
```

Css:

```
#status{
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 0.5em;
    border: 1px solid var(--blue);
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
#status option{
    background-color: var(--body-color);
    color: var(--blue);
}
#status:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0.65em;
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please [edit] your question to add a [mre]. Thanks!

Comment: Show us your html and css (sourcecode) to get the coloring and fx in your image.

Comment: This code you have presented here isn't reproducible because it's insufficient in telling the whole story you describe. That is, there is additional css that you dont include in your question. Instead of posting it all here, could you make a "fiddle" of it and then include the link in your question?

Comment: Not only should you provide the HTML/CSS but also which browser and operating system you're using.  These all factor into how a select element is rendered on the page.  Even if you fix the styling issue for your specific configuration, odds are that you'll have styling issues with a different one.

Answer (score 0):

if any style is not working then you can use `!important` property this will make your style as important and you can use `outline: none` on `focus`.

```css
#status{
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 0.5em;
    border: 1px solid var(--blue);
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    outline: none !important;
}
#status option{
    background-color: var(--body-color);
    color: var(--blue);
}
#status:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0.65em;
}
#status:focus {
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid var(--blue);
}
```

```html
<select name="filtro" id="status">
   <option value="encerrado">Encerrado</option>
   <option value="pendente">Pendente</option>
</select>
```